# How can I get all files matching a query that are both the direct and indirect children of some folder in Drive API?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I already know how to get files that are the direct children of some folder:

```
var x = Drive.Files.list({q: 'title contains "foo bar" and "/* parent folder id */" in parents'})
```

What I would like to know is if there's an easy and efficient way to get all files matching a query string that are the direct or indirect children of some parent folder.

For example, let's say I have a filesystem structure that looks like this:

```
root:
  folderA:
    file1
    foo bar
  folderB:
    file2
    folderBA:
      file3
      file4
      folderBAA:
        foo bar
    folderBB:
      foo bar
      file5
  folderC:
    foo bar
    file6
```

Is there a way to build a query string or use Drive API functions that would get me all files called `foo bar` that are within `folderB`? The result in such a scenario would be `foo bar` within `folderBAA` and `folderBB`, but not under `folderA` and `folderC`

Comment: If "javascript" of your tag includes Google Apps Script, is this information helpful for your situation? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/8e9b6fd667efcb483c9c742da9cd4e19 Unfortunately, by only ``q`` of ``Drive.Files.list()``, all files and folders under a folder cannot be retrieved. So I made this. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The complete search filters for drive api `files.list` are found in [Valid fields for files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#file_fields) and looking at it, there is no filter which selects certain folders only.

Comment: There is and it's the first line of code in my post. Drives.Files.list({q: "'/* folder id */' in parents"}) selects certain a certain folder. But it only returns direct children of that folder. I need the children, grandchildren, great grandchildren, and so on, of that folder.